# twitter bootstrap rendering issue (button styling in the docs differ from local use)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in a project and while reviewing the documentation, i ran into a very odd problem - if that can so be called.

On http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons, there are alot of buttons displayed next to each other. They seem to have spacing, but the computed style (in Firefox and Safari, where i investigated) was the following:

```
margin-top: 0
margin-right: 0
margin-bottom: 0
margin-left: 0
```

This should NOT render into a spacing of 10~px between individual buttons.

The padding of 9/14px seems only to be used to display the button-shape.

Now when i use twitter bootstrap on my own projects, the margin that i see from the twitter bootstrap doc site seems not to work locally - buttons are glued to each other with no spacing. This can be rectified with a simple local `margin`, but i wonder why it differs from the documentation. Also: why does it not show in firebug or the other developer tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the buttons have a property of `display:inline-block` added to them, `display:inline-block` is dependent on font-size that is inherited from their container. If you set the `font-size` on the `p` tags enclosing the buttons to `0` or remove the `html, body` and `p` tags `font-size` you can see how that space is removed.

Comment: I still have trouble recreating this on my local development copy of bootstrap. Thank you very much for the explanation thou. It looks like adding font-size to the container does not add spacing to the buttons, am I not doing enough?

Comment: You have to target all the elements with `font-size` property that are containing your buttons. For example, in the bootstrap demo the `html`, `body` and `p` tag all have the `font-size` property added to them, so you would have to set them to 0 to test it out, or you can simply set `font-size:0` to the container of your buttons and a `font-size` to the elements themselves, e.g. `.container { font-size:0; } .child-element { font-size:16px }`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, while examining your train of thought, i ran into my actual issue - not having whitespace between the `a`-tags. I was not thinking of them as textual content, your approach with font-size led me there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather simple: the surrounding `<td>`s have a style of `padding: 8px` plus a single-pixel border. Removing those removes the perceived margin completely.

Comment: That explains it for the table, but what about the buttons below that are aligned horizontally?